# Cannot Properly Manage Server 2012 r2 Hyper V Core

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

[image]

I have just installed the Hyper V 2012 r2 Core system. I was able to name it, add it to the domain, even RDP into it (which is just worthless).

However, When I open up the Hyper-V Manger on my system, it connects, then takes a long time (upwards of 2 minutes, where ping is less than 1ms) to fully "connect".

There are no virtual machines on the system, because I do not have the option to add them.

There are no actions in the pane but to remove the server. Also they do not show in the right click menu.

I have updated the administration tools, and updated the server.

I am on Win7x64 and am 1 port away from the system on a layer 3 switch.

I am testing this as a possible alternative to VMWare for some remote deployments. I was able to setup VMWare server (version 6 even) and three VMs in a few hours. After two days I am still stuck on this.

Google has not been much help, I can't find much on this out in the ether.

Thoughts, ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Domain environment? User rights properly configured?

Comment: I did successfully add it to my domain, and add not only my self, but two others as local admins. Also domain admin accounts work for connecting, but none of them can actually manage the system to add virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an old version of the Hyper-V manager. You need the Remote Admin Tools for Windows 8.1 to manage 2012 R2. Try managing it from a Windows 8.1 or Server 2012 R2 box.

PowerShell remoting is becoming my favorite way to manage Hyper-V, and that is how I manage my newer hyper-V boxes when I am on a Windows 7 machine. Since you are using the cmdlets on the remote box, you don't even need the RSAT on the local machine. If you are doing a trial deployment, I recommend you try some powershell management too.

Comment: Although I can accept that this is a possibility (needing top be on win8+ to manage a 2012+ server), I have other 2012r2 Hyper V core systems that do not have this problem.

Comment: Here is the compatibility list from Microsoft. [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632582.aspx). I've had mixed luck connecting with old versions of the hyper-v management tools. It seems that Windows 7 Hyper-V manager partially worked with my Hyper-V 2012 systems, but not my 2012 R2 systems.  I hope that is some help.